# ClassCastException with enhanced for loop

Tags: java, enums, coding-style

Inspired by a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012067/creating-all-combinations-using-a-collection-in-java) I was messing around with an experimental Collection:

```
/**
 * Pretends to be a Collection of samples from the items.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
class Samples<T> extends AbstractCollection<T[]> implements Collection<T[]> {

    private final int of;
    private final T[] items;

    public Samples(int of, T... items) {
        this.of = of;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // I know this is wrong.
        return items.length * of;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T[]> iterator() {
        // Make the iterator on the fly.
        return new Iterator<T[]>() {
            // Start at the beginning.
            int which = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // That's how many there are.
                return which < size();
            }

            @Override
            public T[] next() {
                // Make my new one by cloning the original.
                T[] next = Arrays.copyOf(items, of);
                // Pick the items with reference to which.
                int count = which;
                for (int i = 0; i < of; i++) {
                    // count mod length is the next one to use.
                    next[i] = items[count % items.length];
                    // Used that now.
                    count /= items.length;
                }
                // Consumed that one.
                which += 1;
                return next;
            }

        };

    }

}

public void test() {
    Samples<String> samples = new Samples(4, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
    // Walk it with an iterator.
    Iterator<String[]> i = samples.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i.next()));
    }
    // Walk it using enhanced for loop.
    for (String[] s : samples) { // Line 91 - error thrown here.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }
}
```

And found that if I pull an `iterator` out and walk that all works fine but if I try using an enhanced `for` loop it errors with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Is there something I am missing - perhaps insufficient coffee?

Please ignore the incorrect `size` method - I am sure it is not the cause of the problem.

PS: jdk = jdk1.8.0_11 but still fails with jdk1.7.0_65

Comment: Where is the exception originating exactly from? Stacktrace?

Comment: @icza - On the line which reads `for (String[] s : samples) {`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You instantiate a raw type of `Samples` therefore `Samples.items` will be of type `Object[]` not `String[]` in your case. In your `test()` method:

```
Samples<String> samples = new Samples(4, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
```

Change it to:

```
// Note the diamond operator: <>
Samples<String> samples = new Samples<>(4, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
```

As a side note: In your `Samples` class you do not need to state you implement `Collection` because `AbstractCollection` already does.